# How to efficiently convert ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]] into multiple dataframes and write them using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I'm trying to parse a set of XML files using Scala and Spark.I get data for 'n' dataframes from the files.(i.e number of dataframe don't vary, only number of files vary)

I'm parsing a set of XML files and storing the data in `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]]` . Each of the `ListBuffer[String]` contains data for a dataframe.
for eg:

```
ListBuffer[
    ListBuffer["1|2|3|4","5|6|7|8"],
    ListBuffer["a|b|c|d","e|f|g|h"],
    ListBuffer["q|w|e|r","w|x|y|z"]
]
```

This would create 3 dataframe:

```
Dataframe1:
 col1  col2  col3  col4
   1     2     3     4
   5     6     7     8
```

and similarly other 2 Dataframe.

I cannot directly convert XML to Dataframe, as there a lot of custom handling to be done in the data, before making dataframe.

I'm converting the ListBuffer into Dataframe using the following code:

```
finalListBuffer.foreach{ data =>

    columns = FunctionToReturnColumnsList()
    val schema = StructType(columns.map(field => StructField(field, StringType, true)))
    val dataRDD: RDD[Row] = sparkSess.sparkContext.parallelize(data.toStream.map(l => Row.fromSeq(l.split("|", -1))))
    val df = sparkSess.createDataFrame(dataRDD, schema)
    ...
}
```

After this step, some operations are performed on each dataframe, (some operations have inter dataframe dependency, so i cant just process one dataframe, and then write) and finally the dataframes are written using following code:

```
df.repartition(1).write.mode("Overwrite").option("multiline", "true").option("delimiter", "\u0017").csv(filename)
```

While doing these steps, I'm getting 2 issues when input file size is high:

1) GC overhead limit exceeded, while creating the dataframe.(Step where `dataRDD` variable is created)

2) Spark heartbeat timeout error while writing df.

How to solve these issues ?

I was thinking about using `ListBuffer[RDD[String]]` initially, instead of `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]]`

But there can be as many as 1 million files and each files can have upto 10-20 entries for a df. What I'm doing is, I'm listing all the files, and processing each of them one by one, and appending their result, to a main ListBuffer. So, if I'm using RDD, I'll have to use, union for each files, and this can be expensive. What else could be done ?

Comment: So 10 files, each file has >1 DF in it, and each DF has 10-20 entries. Is this right? How many DF in each file?

Comment: No... Totally there are only 'n' DF... For which data comes from 10 files... Each file has 10-20 entry for each DF.... Number of DF's dont vary, with number of files... It will be constant. i.e 'n'....

Comment: OK so what is the value of 'n'?

Comment: It is around 20. It can vary, like from 10-30

Comment: It is not much data to go to the bother of using spark over, but assume you know that. Also its not a lot of data to be out of memory. Have you tried setting the Xmx Xms options to up your heap size?

Comment: In actual case it is not 10 files, it is 1 million, and each df can have upto 10 million rows, at the end of parsing. 

And no i haven't tried Xmx option in the spark submit command.

Comment: I can't help thinking with that many files it will be better to start with a RDD where each element is the representation of the file (the root ListBuffer) then make projections off of that to split into the 'n' dataframes you want

Comment: So are telling to initially read the files as an `RDD[String]` .Then apply a map function to it ? Could you please give a small example if possible. Acually I have a function, that returns `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]]`, if passed an XML file. Currently Iam calling this function for each XML file. I can make them return a `ListBuffer[RDD[String]]` instead, if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

scala> val lbs = ListBuffer(
     |     ListBuffer("1|2|3|4","5|6|7|8"),
     |     ListBuffer("a|b|c|d","e|f|g|h"),
     |     ListBuffer("q|w|e|r","w|x|y|z")
     | )
lbs: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1|2|3|4, 5|6|7|8), ListBuffer(a|b|c|d, e|f|g|h), ListBuffer(q|w|e|r, w|x|y|z))


scala> val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("c1", StringType, true),StructField("c2", StringType, true),StructField("c3", StringType, true),StructField("c4", StringType, true)))
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(c1,StringType,true), StructField(c2,StringType,true), StructField(c3,StringType,true), StructField(c4,StringType,true))

scala> var lb_df: ListBuffer[DataFrame] = ListBuffer()
lb_df: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = ListBuffer()

scala> def createDF(lb: ListBuffer[String]) = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lb.toSeq).map(_.toString.split("\\|")).map(Row(_: _*)), schema)
createDF: (lb: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame


scala> lbs.foreach(lb => lb_df.append(createDF(lb)))

scala> lb_df.foreach(_.show())
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|  5|  6|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
|  e|  f|  g|  h|
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  q|  w|  e|  r|
|  w|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Could you please explain, how this will help in tackling the problems I have mentioned. Does writing the createDF function, helps in tackling problem of GC Overhead limit error ?

Comment: What spark properties you are setting while running this code ? You may have to increase executor and driver memory and also number of executor cores and overhead memory. You may refer My answer in below for spark properties - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168254/how-to-set-amount-of-spark-executors/56720485#56720485

Comment: These are the properties set : `properties spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1,spark.executor.instances=1,spark.executor.memoryOverhead=17408,spark.executor.memory=148G,spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=17408,
spark.driver.memory=148G,spark.executor.cores=32,spark.driver.cores=32,spark.default.parallelism=64` I'm using only one executor, so that driver memory is max, because, the whole listbuffer will be stored in driver memory, as per my understanding.